# Android: how to display textview ending with ellipse followed another textview

Tags: android, textview

I want output like:

```
 |<textview>...<Textview>|
```

Examples:

```
 |Abcdeded, asdasds...(2)|
 |Abcedede, asdaassaa, as
  satlkjkj,asdsadf(3)    |
 |Abdedefr, asdawewer, we
  weqweeqwe.qwewewe...(3)|
```

My textview can have max of two lines.
I have tried using relative layout, linear layout, but not solving my problem.

Comment: may i know why you want to use two textview?

Comment: can you give a better example (more apparent)

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you want to show the ellipsize, if the textview breaches the condition of 2 lines (max characters in 2 lines minus length of 2nd text view)?

Comment: @Sri : i can avoid another textview,...if i'm able to achieve output.

Comment: @Macialov : i just want to display the count of strings at the end. If strings reaches boundary of second line then it should ellipsize and it should number of total strings. That is just to facilate user that these many string are used in total. Since user is not able to view full string, user can get to know total number of strings.

Comment: why don't you use stringbuilder to format the string.If you are not get second string then just skip that one and show string using only one textview.

Answer (score 0):

Believe you want something like that:

```
<LinearLayout ... android:orientation="vertical">
   <LinearLayout ... android:orientation="horizontal">
      <TextView ... android:ellipsize="end">
      </TextView>

      <TextView ....>
      </TextView>
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout ... android:orientation="horizontal">
      <TextView ... android:ellipsize="end">
      </TextView>

      <TextView ....>
      </TextView>
   </LinearLayout>
   .....
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use xml attribute :- android:ellipsize="end" in first TextView property and use second TextView jsut after firstone